# Android Studio doesn't highlight invalid Kotlin receiver when using @IdRes

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, annotations, kotlin-extension

I expected that using extension:

```
fun @receiver:IdRes Int.findView() = findViewById<View>(this)
```

On resource that is not defined in `R.id` would highlight the call, but it doesn't:

[image]

Is this a bug?

**EDIT**

Linked question and answers do not answer this question. In this case, I asked specifically about Kotlin's `@receiver` annotation, not some enum `@IntDef` annotation. Also, the current version of Kotlin is 1.2.51, not 1.0.3

Comment: @DavidRawson How does question from 2 years ago answers this one? There is nothing about receivers

Comment: @IntDef compile time lint check is not fully supported in Kotlin

Comment: @DavidRawson But it's `@IdRes`, not `@IntDef`